# Reid Undergraduate Commutative Algebra Lemma 8.3 - Proof explanation

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, proof-explanation

Lemma. Let $A$ be a Noetherian integral domain and $t \in A$ be a non-unit. Then, $\cap_{n = 1}^{\infty} (t^{n}) = 0$.

The proof goes as follows: Given $0 \neq x \in A$, either $x \notin (t)$ or $x \in (t)$, so that $x = tx'$; now repeat the argument for $x'$. If $x = tx' = t^{2}x'' = \ldots = t^{n}x^{(n)}$, then $(x) \subsetneq (x') \subsetneq \ldots \subsetneq (x^{(n)})$. So this chain must stop; which means that $x^{(n)} \notin (t)$ for some $n$ and $x \in (t^{n}) \setminus (t^{n + 1})$. $QED$

**What I understand in the proof:**

- We have to show that $\cap_{n = 1}^{\infty} (t^{n}) = 0$. I.e.
  $\cap_{n = 1}^{\infty} (t^{n}) \subseteq \{0\}$ and $\cap_{n =
     1}^{\infty} (t^{n}) \supseteq \{0\}$.
- Now, $\cap_{n = 1}^{\infty} (t^{n}) \supseteq \{0\}$ is trivial
  because all $(t^{n})$ are ideals and in particular additive groups,
  i.e. $0 \in (t^{n})$.
- For $\cap_{n = 1}^{\infty} (t^{n}) \subseteq \{0\}$ we must show that $x \in \cap_{n = 1}^{\infty} (t^{n}) \implies x \in \{0\}$. I suppose Reid shows the contrapositive here? I.e. $x \notin \{ 0 \} \implies x \notin \cap_{n = 1}^{\infty} (t^{n})$.
- The chain of ideals $(x) \subsetneq (x') \subsetneq \ldots \subsetneq (x^{(n)})$ must stop because $A$ is Noetherian, i.e. sastisfies the a.c.c.
- We have a strict inclusion because if not, then we would have $(y)
     = (ty)$ for some $y \neq 0$; implying $y = aty \iff y(1 - ty) = 0$ and since we are in an integral domain we do not have zero divisors,
  i.e. $ty = 0$ which contradicts that $t$ is non-unit.

**What I do not understand in the proof:**

- So suppose $0 \neq x \in A$. Then, either $x \notin (t)$ or $x \in (t)$ **(Why?)**. So that $x = tx'$ **(What about the case where $x \notin (t)$?)**.
- When the chain of ideals $(x) \subsetneq (x') \subsetneq \ldots \subsetneq (x^{(n)})$ stops, this means that there is $n$ such that $(x^{(n)}) = (x^{(n + 1)}) = \ldots$ **How does this now imply that $x \notin (t)$?**

Answer (score 1):

The claim that either $x \notin (t)$ or $x \in (t)$ is trivial if you think about it for a moment. Just think in terms of sets. If $U \subset V$, and $v \in V$, then the claim that $v \notin U$ or $v \in U$ is obvious.

Next, recall that (as you wrote in your question) he is trying to show that if $x \neq 0$ then $x$ is not in the intersection. If $x \notin (t)$, then certainly $x$ is not in the intersection and so this case is resolved.

For your last point about when the chain of ideals stops, you need to use that $A$ is an integral domain. I'll leave it to you to think about.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler: $x\neq 0\Rightarrow$ there is a maximal $\,n\,$ with $\,t^n\mid x\,$  (else $(x)\subsetneq (x/t)\subsetneq (x/t^2)\subsetneq \cdots$ is infinite, contra ACC). Thus $\,x\not\in (t^{n+1})\,$ so $\,x\not\in \cap_{k = 1}^{\infty} (t^{k})$.

Comment: Recall: contains = divides for principal ideals, so $\,t\mid y\,\Rightarrow\ y/t\mid y\Rightarrow (y/t)\supseteq (y),\,$ which is *im*proper  $\!\iff\! (y)\supseteq (y/t)\!\iff\! y\mid y/t\!\iff\! t\mid 1\,.$ So $\,t\,$ nonunit $\Rightarrow$ all containments are *proper* in our chain $\,\cdots\,(x/t^{k+1})\supseteq (x/t^k)\cdots,\,$ using $\,y = x/t^k.\ \ $